# Async/await and Columns-Width in a WPF-Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, datagrid

In a WPF-Application with this MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="DasDataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
  <Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" Name="DataGrid">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Homepage" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Homepage}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Date" Binding="{Binding StartDate}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="End Date" Binding="{Binding EndDate}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

the Datagrid is populated as seen in the Code-Behind:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataGrid.DataContext = new ListCollectionView(_employees);

        // either this way:
        FillEmployees();
        // or this:
        FillEmployeesAsync();
    }

    private void FillEmployees()
    {
        _employees.Add(GetEmployee());
    }

    private async void FillEmployeesAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1);
        _employees.Add(GetEmployee());
    }

    private Employee GetEmployee()
    {
        return new Employee
        {
            FirstName = "Thomas", LastName = "Huber", StartDate = new DateTime(2010, 5, 1),
            EndDate = new DateTime(2015, 5, 10), Homepage = new Uri("http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com")
        };
    }

}

public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; } public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; } public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public Uri Homepage { get; set; }
}
```

When you choose the FillEmployessAsync() method, the last column of the Datagrid is awfully cut off, whereas when you choose the FillEmployes() method all columns have a smooth width with an appropriated wrap of the Homepage-value in column 2.

Look at the sync-Result here: https://image.ibb.co/kvm40c/Sync.png

and the async-Result there:   https://image.ibb.co/bCacO7/Async.png

Can anybody explain it?

To be precise: The posted async-method is only a surrogate for a method where you fill the Datagrid by an async-Method with a body like this:

```
           var employees = await GetAllEmployees();
        foreach (var item in employees) { _employees.Add(item); }
```

Also I can circumvent the issue using Cleary's NotifyTaskCompletion class. The reason I would like to fill the ObservableCollection successively (in a ViewModel), is to conserve the sorting (via a CollectionView), when all Items of the Datagrid have to be changed.

Comment: Try to declare the method as `private async Task FillEmployeesAsync()` and call it in an async Loaded event handler: `Loaded += async (s, e) => await FillEmployeesAsync();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can anybody explain it?

I suppose in the first example (FillEmployees()) the "ui thread" gets time to bind AFTER filling the list (because the constructor's commands are executed synchronously) and therefore calculates the column widths with a filled list.

In the second one (FillEmployeesAsync) you give it time to render the ui because "async void methods" run asynchronously without waiting for completion of the awaited code inside the method. In this case the renderered list is empty and a correct width is set (width divided by number of columns). When adding the new item the ui realizes that for example the homepage text is too long and adds some width to its column. The other widths are kept as they are so the other columns are pushed out of the window bounds at the right.

You can tell the datagrid how it should calculate the column widths but I am not sure if they will be calculated automatically after adding an item:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/sizing-options-in-the-datagrid-control

(This is my first stackoverflow answer so please don't cut it to pieces ;-) )

Comment: Yes, you see it in the DataGrid_Loaded event; in the sync case DataGrid's ItemsSource has already items, whereas in the async case the ItemsSource is empty. As workearound I use the MinWidth-Property of DataGridColumn.